# how to ensure thread safe when using IOCP in multithread in windows?

Tags: iocp

if i CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, NULL, 4), then when call PostQueuedCompletionStatus(), the 4 threads  which run GetQueuedCompletionStatus() will maybe be return from GetQueuedCompletionStatus(). so if i want to send some data by PostQueuedCompletionStatus() multitimes, then 4 theads will have opportunity to send data. then the problem is, the same socket will be used in multithreads. will it be thread safe? As the same socket, can i designated to the same thread always?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, rather than subordinate sockets and threads.
It seems important to be able to run WSARecv or WSASend only once on a single socket.
You will be able to control recv and send requests using the flag variable using the _interlocked function.